# PHP: Simple regular expression to match exact length of digits

Tags: php, regex

I am trying a simple regex to match exactly 5 digits from a string. However, this pattern matches for 5 and more than 5.

```
preg_match_all('#[0-9]{5}+#', 'one two 412312 three (51212 four five)', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 41231
        [1] => 51215
    )
)
```

I need it to match exactly 5 digits.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('(\b\d{5}\b)', 'one two 412312 three (51212 four five)', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It matches every group of 5 digits.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `()` as delimiter. It conflicts with the special meaning of `()` in regex.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**word boundaries**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) here and remove the `+` quantifier after the range operator.

```
preg_match_all('~\b\d{5}\b~', $str, $matches);
```

As stated in the comments, if you need to match the five digits in `a51212a` but not `412312` you can use a combination of [**lookaround**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertions.

```
preg_match_all('~(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)~', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: This will fail for a51245 though. Not sure if that is expected to be returned.

Comment: @mdsl Not sure either, OP didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaheads and -behinds for that: `(?<!\d)[0-9]{5}(?!\d)`